# Marking user-made classes as "plugins"

Tags: java, api, interface

I am writing an API which will help others write custom "plugin" classes for my current program.

These plugin classes can come in three possible forms.

- extending JPanel
- implementing Paintable
- a combination of the above

The Paintable interface is simply one method: *paint(Graphics2D g)*.
I will then create new instances of these loaded classes. If the object is found to be a JPanel (via instanceof), create a new button on a JFrame and have it open this JPanel.
If the object is found to be a Paintable, add it to an ArrayList.

However, there is a problem. I will be loading these classes from a different folder using a URLClassLoader. In this folder, there will be classes extending JPanel that are **not** meant to be plugins and thus not meant to be loaded.

So my question is: What would be the best way to prompt users to "mark" their classes as plugins? and how would they "mark" it?

Keep in mind the three possibilities these plugins can show up as. Simply creating an empty class named *Plugin* extending JPanel and extending that to all plugins seems wasteful for those *not* extending JPanel.

Comment: Let them *implement* their plugins an empty interface or let them *annotate* with some annotation class. Why can't you have a separate directory specifically for plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a annotation for classes that are meant to be used as plugin, e.g. something like this:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyPlugin {

}
```

, let users annotate plugins with this annotation and check, if a class is meant to be a plugin like this:

```
boolean isPlugin(Class<?> cl) {
    return cl.getAnnotation(MyPlugin.class) != null;
}
```

Comment: This sounds perfect for what I need. Thank you. I had tried annotations before but I don't know why I haven't thought of it like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of "**marker interface**", i.e. teach the developers to implement this interface in their classes. The interface doesn't need to have methods in it. So you can check easily if a class is meant to be a plugin. By searching the net for "marker interface" you will find some examples for this pattern even in the JDK itself.

When you wrote about your Plugin class extending JPanel you were quite near to my suggestion. But an interface is sufficient, there is no need to have a class for that.

You could even define the interface Paintable as extending the Plugin interface. So that in that case the developers don't have any extra effort.

EDIT: This is the traditional way of doing this that worked since the first releases of Java. The "annotation" solution mentioned in the other answer is the more up-to-date solution but also a bit more difficult to understand for beginners.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know empty interfaces were an accepted idea, I will keep that in mind for the future. This would be fine for what I described in my original post. However, I did not mention that each plugin might have some extra information (simple stuff, like a String) that should be provided. The annotation seems perfect for this.